# How to add support to an external monitor in Android?

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, hardware, kernel, system

My Samsung Dex (with Android 7 in a Samsung Galaxy S8 phone) won't work with my LG 23MT75D-PU monitor. I think because the Android driver are not ready to talk with this monitor yet. I will want to know where i can fire a bug related with that fact or find a fix, by myself.

I really think this is an android question by nature. My Galaxy S8 have not a problem and also i considered, this is not a problem of Samsung Dex, but instead, this is a problem in the Android kernel, because it's where reside the modules to load the most commons drivers by default.

Comment: You should contact Samsung customer support.

Comment: Thanks, I live in Mexico City, and custtumer support really only ask me if i connect the cables correctly to the monitor or then the monitor have a problem. They really don't take in consideration a missing driver or something that really it's in his side. For another hand android developers recommend me the same as you recomed me, because they don't know what Sansung is doing. I ask to LG for tecnical specifications and the monitor satisfy the teoretical requierimens of Sansung Dex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The Samsung Dex work only with an specific voltage, you can not connect it to any different power supply (like the usb ports of your computer). If I connect it to the power manager that come with the phone, it will be working well on my monitor.

Thanks all involved.